# How to generate package BUILD files for Bazel using cargo-raze in Rust?

Tags: rust, bazel, rust-cargo

I've been trying to use Cargo raze with a cargo workspaces project for a while now to generate Bazel build files.

While, in remote mode, it generates the build files to pull remote crates and compile them just fine, doesn't seem to be able to generate the target for the binaries and the libraries in the workspace themselves.

Has anyone got around to solving this problem, or does it simply mean that raze cannot generate these files and that they need to be written manually?

I made an example repository with my issue here: https://github.com/ChetanBhasin/bazel-playground

Note how in both rust-simple and rust-workspace, a BUILD file is not generated.

My Cargo.toml file looks like this:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "foobar-lib",
    "foobar-bin",
]

[workspace.metadata.raze]
workspace_path = "//remote/cargo_workspace/cargo"
gen_workspace_prefix = "remote_cargo_workspace"
genmode = "Remote"
output_buildfile_suffix = "BUILD"
default_gen_buildrs = true
experimental_api = true
render_package_aliases = false
```

I remember creating this issue on GitHub for Raze but never got a reply: https://github.com/google/cargo-raze/issues/418

IIRC, raze used to generate BUILD files for cargo libraries and binaries. Or am I missing something?